# Backpropagation: how do you compute the gradient of the final output with respect to any loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, neural-network

I'm trying to train a simple neural net but I'm unsure of the correct backprop value to use.

I'm using a 2 layer NN (1 input, 1 hidden and 1 output layer), using ReLU activations. Here is my h2

```
h1 = np.maximum(0, X.dot(W1) + b1.T)
h2 = h1.dot(W2) + b2.T
score = h2
```

In this case, if I were to backprop my score with respect to the loss function (cross entropy loss), what should be the correct computation I should use? I'm under the impression that this should always be 1 or at least usually equals to 1 since the final output is linearly related to the loss? On this writing, it doesn't really make sense. But if that's not the case, then what would be the correct computation?

Note that the score has not been directly linked to the cross entropy loss function, as I have not exponentiated the score matrix and do the necessary additions. If I were to link it to the cross entropy loss, then I'd do

```
loss_mat = np.exp(scores) / np.sum(np.exp(scores))
loss_mat = np.log(losses)
loss_mat[:,y] -= 1 #Minus one for the correct label? Why do this?
                   #read this as one of the solutions
```

Thank you.